# Using sqlite database with qt

Tags: sqlite, qt

Here is my code, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong:

```
QSqlDatabase db=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName("thedata.sqlite");
db.open();

QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("SELECT lastname FROM people where firstname='?' ");
query.bindValue(0, lineEdit->text());

bool x = query.exec();

if(x){
   lineEdit_2->setText(query.value(0).toString());
 }

 else {
   QSqlError err;
    err = query.lastError();
    QMessageBox::about(this,"error",err.text()   );
 }
```

When the program is working always it gives the error `parameter count mismatch` I'm using qt 4.8 and its own headers for using sqlite.

I would be very thankful for any advice, though I searched in google i see many posts in this issue but nothing helped me.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you verified that `lineEdit->text()` actually returns something, preferably a string?

Comment: @TimoGeusch yes its sure, I type the first name their.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're prepared statement is wrong, it should be:

```
quary.prepare("SELECT lastname FROM people where firstname=?");
```

Notice that there are no single quotes (`'`) around the placeholder. If you put the quotes, it gets passed as a literal to the database, leaving you with a parameter-less query and code that passes too many parameters.

(Changing that variable name to `query` would be a nice touch too.)

Also you need to check the return value if `QSqlQuery::prepare`, and print out/display the error message you're getting from that if it fails – otherwise `QSqlQuery::exec` resets the current error and you'll get a pretty meaningless error message if there was a problem parsing the prepared statement.

```
if(x){
  lineEdit_2->setText(quary.value(0).toString());
}
```

This is incorrect too. The you need to call (and check the return value of) `query.next()` to position the result set to the first row returned (if there is one). You can't use `.value(X)` before you've called `.next()`.

Comment: now it didn't give eny error but nothing happens. it dont display the lastname in lineEdit_2

Comment: That's a different problem. You need to advance the result set to the first row with `query.next()`, otherwise `query` isn't positioned on a  row.

Comment: ok accepted as answer. thank you very mutch, I would have never found this alone, I was trying to solve this for hours. thanks again... :)